# Access inline javascript variables that are generated via Ajax call? Barba.js question specifically

Tags: javascript, ajax, scope, barbajs

I'm using Barba.js on my website. When the 'Portfolio' page is loaded via Barba.js, I run a function, let's call it `get_portfolio_items()`. There are some inline javascript variables that `get_portfolio_items()` needs to access the values of. If the 'Portfolio' page is the very first page to be loaded, then get_portfolio_items() accesses these variables just fine. However, if another page is loaded first, and then clicked into the Portfolio page, I get the error:

> loadMoreVars is not defined.

Even though I can see loadMoreVars is in the DOM.

How can I access these variables in get_portfolio_items()  ? Thank you!

This is the script in the actual HTML that appears on the new page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var loadMoreVars = {
        postsPerPage : 9,   
        maxNumPages : 6,
      };
</script>
```

This is the function that is called whenever a new page is loaded via Barba.js

```
function get_portfolio_items(){
 alert(loadMoreVars.postsPerPage);
 alert(loadMoreVars.maxNumPages);
}
```

This is the Barba.js code that triggers the function when a new page is loaded.

```
Barba.Dispatcher.on('newPageReady', function(current, prev, container) {
    history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
    get_portfolio_items()
});
```

How can I get the function to see the variables and thus alert them out?

Comment: Can you provide more code? It's kinda hard to understand what is happening.

Comment: Hi there, I edited the above to provide more clarity. Please let me know if that makes sense

Comment: Is the script tag inside the head or body of the page?

Comment: The script that contains 'loadMoreVars' is loaded into the body, and the barba.js and related scripts are initially loaded in the body as well

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but i managed to make it work. It's important to set the variable to the window object.

```
<!-- HTML FILE -->
<script class="loadInlineScript">
  window.loadmoreurl='FOO';
</script>

// JS FILE
Barba.Dispatcher.on('newPageReady', function(currentStatus, oldStatus, container) {
  var inlineScript = $(container).find('script.loadInlineScript')
  inlineScript.each(function(i, elm) {
    eval(elm.innerHTML);
  })
});
```